# java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked

Tags: java, android, throwable

Everytime from other Activity intents to LoginActivity, it will crashes the app.

*Logcat of the error:*

> AccessibilityManager: setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled =
>   false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled
>   = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
>                                                                                          java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked at
>   com.example.feoit.mapmanagement.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:63)

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText email, password;
    Button btnSignIn, forgotpwdbtn, btnRegister;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        forgotpwdbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgotpwdbtn);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        forgotpwdbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }



    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSignIn:
                String email1 = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String password1 = password.getText().toString().trim();
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email1, password1).addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapsTrack.class);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                break;
            case R.id.forgotpwdbtn:
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.btnRegister:
                Intent intentreg = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(intentreg);
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

line 63 of the class is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

*Full logcat error:*

> AccessibilityManager: setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false, mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
>                                                                                          java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
>                                                                                              at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.setStateLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:553)
>                                                                                              at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.tryConnectToServiceLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:636)
>                                                                                              at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.(AccessibilityManager.java:226)
>                                                                                              at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getInstance(AccessibilityManager.java:206)
>                                                                                              at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9920)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.initViewGroup(ViewGroup.java:536)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:525)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:520)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:516)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:512)
>                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.(FrameLayout.java:119)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.(PhoneWindow.java:2330)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3471)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3857)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2046)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:367)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:316)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
>                                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                              at com.example.feoit.mapmanagement.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:63)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2514)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1515)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5717)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Comment: not sure what is stacktrace, I'm sorry I'm quite new, but i edit and put full logcat of the error

Answer (score 2):

Apparently , I have found my solution. I misses a super.onStop() in an Activity, that was careless of me. Apologize and thanks for all of your times!

Comment: please can you be more explicit on how you solved the problem, i have exactly the same problem as you, but i don't still understand how you solved the problem.

Comment: I am able to create this exception by selecting the activity, then going to Fast Reboot, and then reselecting the activity from the tasklist

Comment: I don't have any override for `onStop()`, all my overrides call super, still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the way you try call intent for Login Activity from your mainActivity or where ever you try create the intent I usually use

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Page2.class); // Change to LoginActivity.class
i.putExtra("isNewUser","true"); // Optional 
startActivity(i);
```

You might be doing this already, I'm not sure as your code to call this class isn't included.

Also you should add a default case to your switch statement it could prevent tricky bugs further down the road.

Comment: All of my intents are fine, trying to add default case as you said but still the same